# Public transport options between Kiruna and Bodo, Norway

Tags: trains, norway

I would like to travel between the cities of Kiruna, Sweden and Bodo, Norway through Narvik. The plan is to accomplish the loop by train up in the north.

I can take the train up to Narvik. For the remainder, where there is no railway, which options are feasible that are ideally (enough) in sync with train times? Is it possible to use the Hurtigruten ferry?

My intention was to actually know how to cover the Narvik-Bodo leg and I did not choose the right location for the question. As there are answers already, I will keep the question as-is.

Comment: Kiruna in Norway or Kiruna in Sweden?

Comment: You are right, Kiruna is in Sweden and the focus of my problem is how to go between Narvik and Bodo actually.

Answer (score 3):

Hurtigruten goes only to [Norwegian ports](https://global.hurtigruten.com/ports/) ([map](https://www.norwegiancoastalcruises.com/route-map.pdf)), including Narvik, the closest port to Kiruna. Google Maps [recommends the F8 train from Kiruna to Narvik](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Kiruna,+Sweden/Narvik,+Norway/@68.1649446,16.1909368,7z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x45d08e2ae4257c2b:0x4034506de8c8660!2m2!1d20.225282!2d67.8557995!1m5!1m1!1s0x45db9587c5e41fff:0x7c38e735ee9ff68d!2m2!1d17.4272613!2d68.4384984!5i1?entry=ttu). There is no direct train between Narvik and Bodø.

Comment: Thank you for the map. Even on their website, it is not easily accessible. Narvik is not listed in the ports. Harstad looks to be the closest.

Answer (score 3):

The best option would be to take a train to Narvik, and a bus from there. The bus timetable is here:

https://www.reisnordland.no/rutetabeller-buss-bod